# ¿Cuál es la ventaja de usar el tipo de parámetro LinkedList <T> en comparación con LinkedList?

Tags: java, genericos

Pienso que `LinkedList<T>` tiene como ventaja en frente de su equivalente que no tiene de tipo de parámetro de conocer el tipo de argumento que va a utilizar y forzar el uso de elementos del mismo tipo que hacen que el código sea más legible y claro. Pero aparte de eso, **¿Cuál es la ventaja de usar el tipo de parámetro `LinkedList <T>` en comparación con `LinkedList`?**

Comment: Los genéricos sólo existen en tiempo de compilación, no llegan a la ejecución, así que las ventajas son siempre para hacer el código más robusto y usable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

si usas `LinkedList` en lugar, de por ejemplo, `LinkedList<Casa>` tendrás que hacer un casteo en todas partes para poder acceder a las propiedades y a los métodos de los objetos de tipo casa.

```
// LinkedList<>
LinkedList<Casa> casas = new LinkedList<>();

...

Casa casa = casas.get(0);
String direccion = casa.getDireccion();
System.out.println(direccion);
```

```
// LinkedList
LinkedList casas = new LinkedList();

...

Object object = casas.get(0);
Casa casa = (Casa) object; // Requiere un paso más
String direccion = casa.getDireccion();
System.out.println(direccion);
```

Comment: Realmente no entiendo muy bien la pregunta de @ThePassenger. La misma pregunta se podría hacer sobre cualquier clase que use *geenerics*, es decir un buen número desde Java 5. Con la misma preguntamos *por qué usar generics y no clases no tipadas*. Si esta es la pregunta también tiene respuesta y no es solo el tema del cast a la hora de sacar un elemento de una colección.

Comment: Sí, lo se. Solo le dije una ventaja, aunque la mayor ventaja es la seguridad de tipos y la corrección de errores en tiempo de compilación.

Comment: Tu lo has dicho - la seguridad. Solo el que no ha programado en *pre-java5* no sabe lo que es sacar objetos de un contenedor y no saber que te puedes encontrar. En fin - los ingenieros de Sun por algo inventaron los generics, no era solo por fastidiarnos, creo.